# Spring Boot 2.1 - cannot have hbm2ddl.auto to create tables

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

i'm starting a project with Spring Boot 2.1.1 and i usually use this application.properties to have the DB tables to be created or updated.
I'm using a MySQL DB

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

with this properties i was able to update the schema with Spring boot 1.5, now the application starts but no update is made.

I added, as for the migration guide, `the spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always` prop, but nothing has changed...

If i choose `create` or `create-drop`, i see that Spring tries to run a schema file... so the problem is just with `update`